# Get facebook user email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app and I'm trying to get a user's email, but I get

```
Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components: /email
```

on using the following code:

```
$email= idx($facebook->api('me/email'),'data',array());
function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I use normally:

```
$user_profile = $fb->api('/me');
$email=$user_profile['email'];
```

so basically you can do it:

```
$email=idx($facebook->api('/me'),'email',array());
```